# Vue router mounted twice when switching page

Tags: vue.js

I'm using [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/) for switching pages. Now I have two Vue documents:

- Page1.vue
- Page2.vue

In both .vue pages I'm using the `mounted()` instance. In Page1.vue the code starts listening to a socket connection. When I switch to Page2 and back to Page1, it starts listening twice to the socket connection.

I've tested with a simple console.log('Page1.vue') and Page2.vue in page2. When I switch pages, it will console.log multiple times, for each time I switch a page, it will do an extra console.log.

I tried to only execute the code in `mounted()` instance once, but after switching pages, it doesn't do anything.

How can I take care it only mounts once, or do I need to unmount just before switching page? If so, how can I do that?

Page1.vue and Page2.vue

```
<template>
  // The template
</template>
<script>
var socket = io(window.SOCKET_URL, {secure: true});

export default {

    mounted(){
        socket.on('channel:listen', function (data) {
            console.log('Page1.vue');
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**Solution**

```
<template>
  // The template
</template>
<script>
var socket;

export default {
    beforeCreate() {
        socket = io(window.SOCKET_URL, {secure: true});
    },

    mounted(){
        socket.on('channel:listen', function (data) {
            console.log('Page1.vue');
        }
    },

    beforeDestroy() {
        socket.close();
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please share fiddle or live demo of this ?

Comment: turn off the listener in [beforeDestroy](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeDestroy) ?

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you switch the routes the component related to the previous route is destroyed.

So when you switch from Page1 to Page2 , the Page1 component is destroyed. Then when you revisit the route related to Page1 , its instance created again, thus calling all of it lifecycle methods again including `mounted()` where you start listening to you socket.

This is the default behavior of vue. So to tell vue from destroying the components make use of [`<keep-alive>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components).

`<keep-alive>` caches the inactive component.

So wrap your router-view  with keep-alive as:

```
<keep-alive>
   <router-view>
</router-view>
```

This caches all the component instances that appear in the router-view.

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/rvams1993/pen/JvEgaN?editors=1011).

If you dont want to cache all the routes from the router-view, you can use the [`include` or `exclude`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive) attributes on `<keep-alive>`. This tells `<keep-alive>` which component instances to cache.

So add `name` properties to the route components you want to cache.

```
//Page1 component script

export default{
    name: 'page1',
    ...
}


<keep-alive include="page1">  
    <router-view></router-view>
</keep-alive>
```

The above code only caches Page1 component

Answer (score 4):

alternatively, you can remove the event listener in `beforeDestroy`

```
export default {
  methods: {
    channelListener(data) {
      console.log("Page1.vue");
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    socket.on("channel:listen", this.channelListener);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    socket.off("channel:listen", this.channelListener);
  }
};
```